# SQL - Find max based on contents of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, function, aggregate

There has to be an elegant way to do this, but I'm stuck.

I have a table with chemistry data. Some values are 'equal to' and some are 'less than' the reported value, and this is denoted in an adjacent column (with '<' or '='). I've inserted an example below.

I need a query that will return the max value for each element that's associated with an '=' if there is one, even if there are higher values associated with '<'. Or if the highest value is associated with '=', or if all values are '<', just return the highest value. In the example below, I'd need to return Copper = 10, Nickel = 10, but Lead = 9.

Seems simple, but I just can't work it out. Any help is, as always, much appreciated.

```
------------------------------
-- Table structure for `chem`
------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chem`;
CREATE TABLE `chem` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Element` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`Value` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`Qualifier` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of chem
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('2', 'Copper', '1', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('3', 'Copper', '1', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('4', 'Copper', '3', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('5', 'Copper', '4', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('6', 'Copper', '5', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('7', 'Copper', '6', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('8', 'Copper', '7', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('9', 'Copper', '8', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('10', 'Copper', '9', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('11', 'Copper', '10', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('12', 'Nickel', '1', '<');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('13', 'Nickel', '2', '<');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('14', 'Nickel', '3', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('15', 'Nickel', '4', '<');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('16', 'Nickel', '5', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('17', 'Nickel', '6', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('18', 'Nickel', '7', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('19', 'Nickel', '8', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('20', 'Nickel', '9', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('21', 'Nickel', '10', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('22', 'Lead', '1', '<');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('23', 'Lead', '2', '<');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('24', 'Lead', '3', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('25', 'Lead', '4', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('26', 'Lead', '5', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('27', 'Lead', '6', '<');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('28', 'Lead', '7', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('29', 'Lead', '8', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('30', 'Lead', '9', '=');
INSERT INTO `Chem` VALUES ('31', 'Lead', '10', '<');
```

Comment: Your test data is missing a case — an element with all "<" qualifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is to use a CASE statement within your MAX statement.  This is a common way to do SUMIF, COUNTIF, etc. type statements in SQL.  This trick extends will to many situations where you want to filter the value that you're aggregating.

This solution is very efficient because it only requires a single scan of the dataset, unlike solutions with a join or a union.

For example:

```
SELECT Element
       ,COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Qualifier = '=' THEN Value ELSE NULL END), MAX(CASE WHEN Qualifier = '<' THEN Value ELSE NULL END))
FROM chem
GROUP BY Element
```

Comment: +1 : Change this to `COALESCE(MAX(), MAX())` and you get exactly what the OP wants.  Also, this does it in a single scan of the data *(Others here require two scans)*, and without JOINs, UNIONs, etc.

Comment: Yes, with COALESCE added this is best solution.

Comment: Awesome. A little tweaking and it worked like a charm. Thanks for teaching me a new, useful function.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT Element, MAX(Value) FROM Chem WHERE Qualifier = '=' GROUP BY Element
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Element, MAX(Value) FROM Chem C1 WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Chem WHERE Element = C1.Element AND Qualifier = '=')
   GROUP BY Element
```

This performs two queries and assembles the results into a single result set.

The first query finds the maximum Value for each Element that has an "=" qualifier.  The second query handles the other case, in which there's no "=" qualifier, and returns the maximum Value for each of this set of Elements.

Comment: I don't think this will work in the case that there are records for the same element with both '=' and non-'=' qualifiers. I would expect two rows in that case.

Comment: Why do you expect that?  The first query includes only elements *with*  "=" qualifiers, the second query includes only elements *without* "=" qualifiers.  Looking at the sample data, the second query would not add any records to the result set.  The second query does handle the missing test case, in which all records have "<'.

Comment: NOT EXISTS can be very slow especially with a subquery.  I believe a LEFT JOIN would be a lot faster.

Comment: Faster is good (and a correlated NOT EXISTS like this will truly be slow), but only if you get the correct result.  I don't know how you'd solve this with a JOIN only.

Comment: @Larry Lustig - because the GROUP BY is applied to each query before the UNION ALL. If you have both qualifier='=' and qualifier<>'=' rows, you will get two GROUP BY results fed into the UNION ALL yielding two results for a given element. Flaw in my logic here?

Comment: With an Index covering `(Element, Qualifier, Value)` are you *certain* that MySQL can't optimise the `NOT EXISTS` version appropriately?  Other RDBMSes can, and I would expect it to be extremely efficient on them.  *[Assuming a large enough data-set to make indexes relevant.  The example here would be too small.]*

Comment: @saarp - Three groups `('=' only)`, `('=' and '<' mix)`, `('<' only)`.  Query one gives the correct answer for both of the first two groups, and no answer for the second group.  Query two gives the answer for the third group, and no answer for the first two groups.  *[Because the `GROUP BY` is applied after the `WHERE` clause.]*

Comment: @ChrisGessler: Please don't edit answers this way.  For clarity or formatting, yes.  But don't add content.  Your answer using JOIN should be posted separately (among other things, that way *you* can get credit for it, not me).

Comment: @saarp: As Dems points out, the Elements included in the second SELECT GROUP BY query will not also be present in the results from the first query, so no duplicate results.

Comment: @LarryLustig - just trying to help